# How to create an array/object from an ordered list?

Tags: javascript

How can I create an array or object from an ordered list, with the number as the index/key and the list item as the corresponding value?

Example list:

```
<ol>
  <li>First list item</li>
  <li>Second list item</li>
  <li>Third list item</li>
</ol>
```

Should result in:

```
{"1" => "First list item", "2" => "Second list item", "3" => "Third list item"}
```

I tried using `Array.from()` with a few variations but that didn't work

Comment: Why do you want an object instead of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write a query selector to get the `<ol>` tag and then read its children:

```js
let ol = document.querySelector('ol')
let lis = ol.children
```

Then, define an object and aggregate all the `<li>` texts into it:

```js
let obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  obj[i.toString()] = lis[i].innerText
}
```

That should create the object you're looking for.

Comment: All the answers are great but this is the first one I saw and it worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use querySelectorAll to get the `<li>`s and iterate over them to extract their `innerText` into an array:

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map(x => x.innerText);

console.log(items);
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First list item</li>
  <li>Second list item</li>
  <li>Third list item</li>
</ol>
```

The resulting array will have `item[0] === 'First list item'`, etc.

Comment: thank you, this is great, but I just happened to see the first answer already which worked (unless you think it has something wrong with it?)

Comment: Not quite how I would do it, and it strikes me as odd to use an object with numeric keys (as opposed to an array) but that's specifically what you asked for.

Comment: The reason I wanted an object is because I am using this object in the backend to update a table in the DB, and the key is the `id` and the value is the value I update, so I get all the data in the same object which makes it easier on the backend

Comment: Counting on the order in the DOM to line up with DB ids seems like A Bad Idea™ to me, but maybe I'm missing some context that makes it make sense. (And in the accepted answer the first index will be `"0"`, not `"1"`.)

Comment: Nice catch on the `"0"`, I then changed the for loop to start from `1` and end at `<=`.
The backend itself has more validation to make sure the order makes sense with only valid inputs, i.e. checking that it's only numbers, and that it only contain the numbers that were in the original order in the db. So if the data from the db contain order with numbers from 1 to 5, then the new order must contain all the numbers from 1 to 5 and not repeating

Comment: If you must use the DOM as the source of truth on the IDs you could be explicit about it with something like `<li data-id=“3”>` instead of relying on DOM order.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do that:

```js
let bob = Array.from( document.querySelector('ol').children, li => li.textContent )

console.log( bob)
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First list item</li>
  <li>Second list item</li>
  <li>Third list item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: thank you, since I saw the other answer first and it worked I marked it, sorry for not marking yours as best, but this is working as well